# Can an open ball be a closed set and cannot be interpreted as a closed ball at the same time?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

For example, in the metric space $E=(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup(2,3)$ with normal distance, $(1,2)=\{x:d(x,\frac{3}{2})<\frac{1}{2}\}$ is an open ball, and $(1,2)$ is also a closed set. However, we also have $(1,2)= \{x:d(x,\frac{3}{2})\leq \frac{1}{2}\}$, which is a closed ball, so $(1,2)$ cannot be served as a supportive example.

I would also like to know the answer of the mirror question: Can a closed ball be an open set and cannot be interpreted as an open ball at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Consider the set$$[2,\infty)\cup\left\{1,0,-2(=-1-1),-1-\frac12,-1-\frac13,-1-\frac14,\ldots\right\}.$$Then the closed ball with center $0$ and radius $1$ is an open set, but *not* an open ball.

Now, fro the question from the title, consider$$(-\infty,-2)\cup(-2,-1)\cup(-1,0]\cup\{2\}.$$Then the open ball with center $0$ and radius $2$ is a closed set which is not an closed ball.

Comment: This seems to answer only half of the question?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Right. I had not noticed that the question from the title was not the one from the body.  It's done now.